# getting error for using "factorplot" in seaborn in python

Tags: python

Why am I getting this error when trying to create a factorplot? Other plots like line, bar, etc work fine. I am using python 3.10 (64-bit).

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.factorplot(data=auto, x="fuel-type", y="horsepower", hue="num-of-doors")
plt.show()
```

> AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'factorplot'. Did
> you mean: 'scatterplot'?

Answer (score 1):

sns.factorplot > sns.catplot

`sns.factorplot(data=auto, x="fuel-type", y="horsepower", hue="num-of-doors")`

Replace the above code with the following

`sns.catplot(data=auto, x="fuel-type", y="horsepower", hue="num-of-doors", kind = 'point')`

factorplot has been changed to catplot.